# Why won't my upload script work? It gives a server error when it is run

Tags: php, upload

The code is [here](https://gist.github.com/4155885):

```
// In PHP versions earlier than 4.1.0, $HTTP_POST_FILES should be used instead
// of $_FILES.

$uploaddir = '/var/www/upload/';
$uploadfile = $uploaddir . basename($_FILES['uploaded'].['name']);

echo '<pre>';
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['uploaded']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) {
    echo "File is valid, and was successfully uploaded.\n";
} else {
    echo "Possible file upload attack!\n";
}

echo 'Here is some more debugging info:<br>';
print_r($_FILES);
echo "<br>";
print_r($uploadfile);
print "</pre>";
```

It gives [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8EpPM.png) error. 
I know it makes it really not secure and I'm going to undo it but I made the entire directory that the website is in a public read/write directory, just to see if it would work. It still doesn't.

Comment: You should check your web server's error log for the *real* PHP error.

Comment: Do not use internet explorer for testing websites, or at least disable the setting "Show friendly HTTP error messages".

Answer (score 2):

Line 6 you have a `.` between `$_FILES['uploaded'].['name']`

Comment: I did that. That gave me my error message:
`Possible file upload attack!
Here is some more debugging info:Array
(
    [uploaded] => Array
        (
            [name] => bicon.c
            [type] => text/plain
            [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpZfCLsM
            [error] => 0
            [size] => 683
        )

)
../var/www/upload/bicon.c`